# Nginx routing problem: subpage refresh goes to DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN error

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am new to web development and I am trying to develop my own website.

I am trying to set up server-side routing to fix the problem that whenever I refresh, the page goes to 404 Error. I solved this by setting up my Nginx file:

```
server{
        root /var/www/build;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name langyinan.com www.langyinan.com;

        location / {
               try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
}
```

That solved the 404 problem for all my subpage that goes directly under my domain:

https://langyinan.com/about_me, https://langyinan.com/project_gallery, all of these works.
However, when I try to access this link by copying and pasting the URL https://langyinan.com/project_gallery/scatter_gather, I get an error:
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

When I access this link by clicking on the button that directs to it, everything works fine.

I am guessing it is because I only set up one location block?
But what is the best practice here?

Here is my front end routing:

```
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path = '/' component = { Main } />
                <Route exact path = '/project_gallery/scatter_gather' component = { Scatter_Gather } />
                <Route exact path = '/project_gallery' component = { Project_Gallery } />
                <Route exact path = '/about_me' component = { About_Me } />
                <Route exact path = '/my_resume' component = { My_Resume } />
                <Route exact path = '/login' component = { Login } />
              </Switch>
```

I have also tried to set up a route.js file to manage the routing, but from what I understand I need to set up a proxy to a node.js server running on pm2. Please correct me if I'm wrong so that I can avoid making stupid mistakes!

Comment: What you are describing is a DNS error and has nothing to do with the nginx/react. A very weird wild guess - can't it be some cached redirect in your browser? Can you try the same from the incognito window?

Comment: The incognito window shows me the same result.

Comment: Sounds weird. Can you check `curl -I https://langyinan.com/project_gallery/scatter_gather` or `curl -v https://langyinan.com/project_gallery/scatter_gather` and post the results somewhere or add them to yuor question?

Comment: curl: (6) Could not resolve host: langyinan.com

Here is what I got from curl -I.

Thank you very much for answering my question, regardless I'm grateful for your response!

Comment: `langyinan.com` domain cannot be resolved by your DNS server. Once again, this has nothing to do with nginx or react. Another guess - you have a valid NS record of type A or CNAME for `www.langyinan.com` but don't have a record for `langyinan.com`. Usually when you visit `www.langyinan.com` site most browsers will hide that `www.` prefix from the address bar. Try the same `curl` command with `www.langyinan.com` domain instead of `langyinan.com` one.